# error: unexpected argument '--ws-port' found

Tags: polkadot

I meet this error when create a new note. On stackoverflow, and in the suggested tip, it is replaced to --rpc-port, but in the argument there was  an existing --rpc-port argument with a different value. what to do in this case?

> ./target/release/node-template 
> --base-path /tmp/node01 
> --chain ./customSpecRaw.json 
> --port 30333 
> --ws-port 9945 
> --rpc-port 9933 
> --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" 
> --validator 
> --rpc-methods Unsafe 
> --name MyNode01 
> --password-interactive

error: unexpected argument '--ws-port' found

tip: a similar argument exists: '--rpc-port'

Comment: Please mark the response from xavier as "Answer" if it answered your question. This makes it easier for other people to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--rpc-port` instead.

For more detail, see https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.43.

Comment: how about the existing  --rpc-port 9933?

Comment: Yep, that's the right one to use.